# Should I add rel nofollow to internal links which already have meta noindex?

Tags: seo, nofollow, noindex

Let's say I have a products page with listing producsts and the page has pagination. I would like the 1st page to have all the SE ranking weight so I decided to put `meta noindex` on the rest of the paginated pages (from page 2 to N).

My common sense says that if I don't want pages to not get indexed, I shouldn't also pass link/PR juice to these pages. (Is that smart?)

What happens if I set `rel="nofollow"` for all pagination links from page 2 to page N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes a difference. The bots do this:

- Go to `noindex.html`. Crawl it, check it, do all the usual checks, **get all internal links**
- Don't index this page, because `rel="noindex"`
- Repeat for each internal link

As you can see, it still follows all internal links, it just doesnt index `no-index.html`. This means `internal-linked-page.html` will get found, crawled and indexed.

If you add `nofollow` to your `noindex.html` page, this will happen:

- Go to `noindex.html`. Crawl it, check it, do all the usual checks, **Don't follow internal links**

---

As for your situation, [pagination with rel=“next/prev”](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html). This will indicate `same result, page 2`.